# Corda - Queries on QueryableState Child Tables

Tags: corda

### Background

I have a problem with being able to query child data in a sample Corda application, demonstrating how to persisnt hierarchical data using `QueryableState`.

For reference:

- https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/tree/master/Features/queryableState-carinsurance
- https://www.corda.net/blog/persisting-corda-states-in-custom-database-tables-using-queryablestate/

The car insurance sample demonstrates how to set up:

- a One-to-One relationship between `PersistentInsurance` and `PersistentVehicle`
- a One-to-Many relationship between `PersistentInsurance` and `PersistentClaim`

### Problem

What the car insurance sample doesn't demonstrate is how to query that data. Building vault queries from `PersistentInsurance` is fairly trivial as we can use `VaultCustomQueryCriteria` to build custom query expressions over the properties of `PersistentInsurance`, however the same is not true for the child tables in the hierarchy. This is because `PersistentInsurance` extends `PersistentState`, whereas `PersistentVehicle` and `PersistentClaim` don't.

For Reference, the underlying type hierarchy for `PersistentState` is as follows:

`StatePersistable` > `DirectStatePersistable` > `PersistentState`

```kotlin
interface StatePersistable

interface DirectStatePersistable : StatePersistable {
    val stateRef: PersistentStateRef?
}

class PersistentState(@EmbeddedId override var stateRef: PersistentStateRef? = null) : DirectStatePersistable

data class PersistentStateRef(
        @Suppress("MagicNumber") // column width
        @Column(name = "transaction_id", length = 144, nullable = false)
        var txId: String,

        @Column(name = "output_index", nullable = false)
        var index: Int
) : Serializable {
    constructor(stateRef: StateRef) : this(stateRef.txhash.toString(), stateRef.index)
}
```

Going back to the car insurance sample, we can't use `VaultCustomQueryCriteria` for `PersistentVehicle` or `PersistentClaim` as `VaultCustomQueryCriteria::expression` has a generic constraint on `StatePersistable`:

```kotlin
data class VaultCustomQueryCriteria<L : StatePersistable>(
    val expression: CriteriaExpression<L, Boolean>,
    ...
) : CommonQueryCriteria() { ... }
```

### What I've Tried

Implementing `StatePersistable` on `PersistentVehicle` and/or `PersistentClaim` causes the following error when you create a `VaultCustomQueryCriteria` using any of the properties from those classes:

> net.corda.core.node.services.VaultQueryException: Parsing error: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [stateRef] on this ManagedType [...$PersistentClaim]

Implementing `DirectStatePersistable` or `PersistentState` on `PersistentVehicle` and/or `PersistentClaim` causes an internal error when finalizing the transaction. The flow hangs and eventually times out. I wasn't able to determine exactly where the error occurs as the code is buried inside internal implementations for underlying Corda services.

### What Does Work (In a Limited Capacity)

I'm aware that we can execute custom SQL queries; for example:

```kotlin
val sqlQuery = buildString {
    appendln("SELECT TRANSACTION_ID, OUTPUT_INDEX")
    appendln("FROM CLAIM_DETAIL")
    appendln("WHERE claimNumber = '123'")
}

val stateRefs = serviceHub.jdbcSession().executeCaseInsensitiveQuery(sqlQuery).map {
    val txId = SecureHash.parse(it.getString("TRANSACTION_ID")
    val index = it.getInt("OUTPUT_INDEX")
    StateRef(txId, index)
}.toList().toBlocking().first()

VaultQueryCriteria(stateRefs = stateRefs)
```

Needless to say, that's hideous compared to:

```kotlin
VaultCustomQueryCriteria(PersistentClaim::claimNumber.equal("123"))
```

As for why it works in a limited capacity, this works fine for queries inside the node, which access to the service hub, but doesn't work over RPC as there's no access to a `jdbcSession`.

So, any ideas (if it's at all possible), on how we can improve the query capability of child tables?

Comment: An update - In discussion with the team. Will get back to you on this.

Answer (score 0):

@Matthew Layton I have put your concerns to the engineering team. The team has looked into this.

**To address/fix this issue, requires lot of platform changes.**

For time being I would suggest you to manage with using native queries. We are planning to prioritise this issue. I will keep you posted on this.